# How to shadow everything and disable all other jQuery functions on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this ajax function:

```
function callpage() {
    $('#formcontent').empty().html('<p class="vent">Pleace wait</p>');
    var form = $('form#sog');
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#formcontent').css("border", "none").html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

When it is called I want to shadow everthing else, then the formcontent div and all other jquery functions should be disabled until the ajax call has succeeded.

Update:
My toggle function that should be disabled when callpage is called until it is succeeded:

```
$('#search').hover(
    function () {
        $('#search').animate({width: '400px'}, 500, function() {});
    },
    function () {
        $('#search').animate({width: '200px'}, 500);
        callpage();
    }
);
```

Comment: I think he wants a modal window.

Comment: I mean fade : ) Yes modal window

Comment: be sure to put `async: false,` in your ajax so that it waits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call an overlay when the AJAX call start with [AJAXStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and then hide it with [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $("#overlay").show();
 });

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   $("#overlay").hide();
 });
```

Or you can put everything in the call:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            beforeSend: function(){$("#overlay").show();},
            complete: function(){$("#overlay").hide();},
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success:function(msg){$('#formcontent').css("border", "none").html(msg);}
            });
```

EDIT i take the overlay from the other answer

```
#modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    opacity: .75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

For your function you could add some extra logic and check if the overlay is visible or not

```
 $('#search').hover( 
  function () {
        var overlayDisplayed = $("#overlay").is(":visible");
        if(!overlayDisplayed){
          $('#search').animate({width: '400px'}, 500, function() { });
         }
  },
  function () {
        var overlayDisplayed = $("#overlay").is(":visible");
        if(!overlayDisplayed){
          $('#search').animate({width: '200px'}, 500);
          callpage();
         }
  }
);
```

Comment: My toggle function still works when model-overlay is showed. I have updated my question with the function.

Comment: @Railsbeginner i updated my answer. Basically you could check in your function if the overlay is visible or not and then act accordingly

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eys3d/741/) and [here](http://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/) another with **more overlay effects**. Hope helps.

Answer (score 2):

People usually code an overlay div with the CSS like:

```
#modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    opacity: .75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So, when it's loading you just call `$("#modal-overlay").show()` (or `$("#modal-overlay").fadeIn()`) and when it finishes loading you just call `$("#modal-overlay").hide()` (or `$("#modal-overlay").fadeOut()`).

This div goes over all the rest of the elements so you don't need to disable all the other jQuery functions.

Comment: I can't see any toggle call in your code, can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

To disable other functionality call ajax with this parameter:

```
async : false // (default: true)
// http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```

To shadow you can create a semi-transparent div on the top (I won't describe the process) with width and height of the browser window on **beforeSend** and remove it on **success**, **error** or **complete** (depends of what method will you use).

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete solution which I am using: (As I posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43490514/1726296)

Following are the sections:

1. CSS for overlay. "fixed" is used to cover whole page content, not just screen height and widths. You can use background color or gif
2. Attaches to "beforeSend" event of jQuery Ajax call. Creates the overlay on demand and shows it.
3. Upon completion of request, it removes the overlay from DOM

CSS:

```
.request-overlay {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed; /*Important to cover the screen in case of scolling content*/
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.5) url('../../Images/submit-ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center; /*.gif file or just div with message etc. however you like*/
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/*your url*/',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('body').append('<div id="requestOverlay" class="request-overlay"></div>'); /*Create overlay on demand*/
                    $("#requestOverlay").show();/*Show overlay*/
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    /*actions on success*/
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    /*actions on error*/
                complete: function () {
                    $("#requestOverlay").remove();/*Remove overlay*/
                }
            });
```

About "disable all other jquery functions on ajax call" in your question ? What do you mean ? Even though Ajax calls as async in nature, usually, calls are implemented in sync by developer. There are rare cases where there will be parallel Ajax calls happening simultaneously in a page. In that case, its up to the developer to have appropriate techniques.