# Jquery - How to disable the entire page

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I have this ajax event

```
function save_response_with_ajax(t){
  var form = $('#edit_'+t);
  var div = $('#loading_'+t);
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"), 
    type: "POST",    
    data: form.serialize(), 
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
      form.hide();
      div.show();
    },
    complete: function(){
      div.hide();
      form.show();
    },
    success: function (result) {
    }       
  });
}
```

And everything works fine, but I want to add (if it's possible) the hability of turning the entire page (the content/body) into gray while before/complete ajax events, like if it were a modal (like this http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal but without the dialog)

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Javier Q.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A way of doing this is having an overlay element which fills the entire page. If the overlay element has a semi-transparent background color, it grays out the page completely: http://jsfiddle.net/SQdP8/1/.

Give it a high `z-index` so that it's on top of all other elements. That way, it renders correctly, and it catches all events (and won't pass them through).

```css
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}​
```

Comment: It works fine... but if the ajax event is not completed... I can click that background, I guess I have to edit my question and ask if there's a way of avoid users click other place while they wait... Thanks :)

Comment: @JavierQQ23: Well I put that in the fiddle so that you can try again (the fiddle doesn't do the ajax, it just shows the overlay). Just don't include the `.click` part.

Comment: Thanks! it works! with a little of delay but I have to handle this :)

Comment: `rgba()` doesn't work in any IE < 9, so the overlay won't block any clicks, you also need a default if you want to use `rgba()`

Comment: `background-color: black; opacity: 0.8;` may also work. For IE it will just be completely black.

Comment: @ckozl well that's a problem, how can I solve it? because at least it should work on IE8

Comment: opacity doesn't work in IE < 9 either, if I was already using jQuery UI either use `.dialog` as I illustrated below or at least use the class `ui-widget-overlay` as it handles some of this...

Comment: That's what I meant; on IE < 9 it will just be completely black.

Comment: @pimvdb then how (for example) jquery shows that modal background?

Comment: @JavierQQ23: With a completely black solid background color - try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQdP8/2/.

Comment: Why the display:none ?

Comment: POsition should be fixed here, because if you scroll further gray overlay stays on top of the page.

Answer (score 6):

you can try

```
 $("body").append('<div id="overlay" style="background-color:grey;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:999"></div>');
```

then just use

> $("#overlay").remove();

to get rid of it.

quick & dirty.

Comment: You're missing the closing quotes, I corrected it, otherwise `append` doesn't work in latest jQuery

Comment: I believe .remove() only works with a class selector.

Answer (score 3):

Try appending an overlay during the "beforeSend" function:

```
$("body").prepend("<div class=\"overlay\"></div>");

$(".overlay").css({
    "position": "absolute", 
    "width": $(document).width(), 
    "height": $(document).height(),
    "z-index": 99999, 
}).fadeTo(0, 0.8);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the complete solution which I am using:

Following are the sections:

1. CSS for overlay. "fixed" is used to cover whole page content, not just screen height and widths. You can use background color or gif
2. Attaches to "beforeSend" event of jQuery Ajax call. Creates the overlay on demand and shows it.
3. Upon completion of request, it removes the overlay from DOM

CSS:

```
.request-overlay {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed; /*Important to cover the screen in case of scolling content*/
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.5) url('../../Images/submit-ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center; /*.gif file or just div with message etc. however you like*/
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/*your url*/',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('body').append('<div id="requestOverlay" class="request-overlay"></div>'); /*Create overlay on demand*/
                    $("#requestOverlay").show();/*Show overlay*/
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    /*actions on success*/
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    /*actions on error*/
                complete: function () {
                    $("#requestOverlay").remove();/*Remove overlay*/
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `ajaxStart()` to append a Div to your document. Set it to the size of your document with some form of semi-transparent document. Then remove it on `ajaxStop()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var modal = $('<div>')
  .dialog({ modal: true });

modal.dialog('widget').hide();

setTimeout(function() { modal.dialog('close'); }, 2000); // to close it
```

here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/avoyut/3/edit#javascript,html,live

don't forget to call `modal.dialog('close');` to end it all!

this way you get the benefits of the actual dialog modal code, resizing, disabling, etc..

hope this helps -ck

Comment: I did this:
beforeSend: function(){
      $('<div>')
  .dialog({ modal: true })
  .dialog('widget')
  .hide();
    },
but nothing seems to happen (it blocks but the gray background is not working)

Comment: do you have a jQuery UI css? and does that css have a overlay associated with it?

Comment: well now its working but, in the beginning of the function I stated var modal = .....hide(); and inside the beforeSend: function(){ modal }, complete: function() { modal.dialog('close'); }, is that correct? or I stated it wrong? Thanks

Comment: my apologies if you look at the edited code it demonstrates what needs to be done, problem was .dialog('widget') changes the chainable return

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give the user some indication that something is happening, too, not just a blank/gray screen. I would suggest some sort of loading gif, see [this](http://skfox.com/2008/04/28/jquery-example-ajax-activity-indicator/), for example.

Comment: Actually there's a gif (div.show()) and it blocks the radio buttons of the form, but there are other links that I want to users avoid clicking when the ajax event has started

Answer (score 0):

Today I was looking for a solution which would work for all browsers of IE. I took the code of `@pimvdb` and `@Ash Clarke` along with his comment where he mentioned *`background-color: black; opacity: 0.8; may also work. For IE it will just be completely black.`* and came to a solution below:

```
$("#first-div").prepend("<div class=\"overlay-example\"></div>");

var height1 = $("#first-div").height();
var width1 = $("#first-div").width();

$(".overlay-example").css({
    "background-color": "black",
    "z-index": "9999999",
    "position": "absolute",
    "width": width1,
    "height": height1,
    "display": "none"
}).fadeTo(0, 0.0001);
```

Tested in IE8, IE9 above. Could not check for IE7. Will be glad to update my soulution in case you find it wrong. *(it would help me also to update my solution :))*

Thank you `@pimvdb` and `@Ash Clarke`

[<kbd>***Demo***</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/cogozoxuju/2/edit?output)