# Disable page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My search textbox is positioned in header. On typing in textbox, I want to disable rest of the page(except header). The page should be greyed out.Two separate div are there: header and main. Main div contains several sub div to structure the content.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you please post your full code?

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416556/jquery-how-to-disable-the-entire-page

Comment: please create jsfiddle or post full code here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using css properties.

```js
$("#text1").keydown(function() {
$(".main").css({
    "text-indent": "-9999px",
    "background-color": "gray"
})
});

$("#text1").focusout(function() {
$(".main").css({
    "text-indent": "0px",
    "background-color": "red"
    
})
});
```

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
    <input type="text" id="text1">
</div>

<div class="main">Content that is going to hide when textbox is changed</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: on focus out it main div doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

@Thinker solution is good (although I'm not sure if using `"text-indent": "-9999px"` is a good practice). Another option is to add another div upon your main div and play with the opacity setting to achieve a suitable result. Have in mind that a container div is needed though as main div's parent, look at the demo:

```js
$("#text1").keydown(function() {
    $(".main").append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
});
```

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: red;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:grey;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
    <input type="text" id="text1">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Content that is going to hide when textbox is changed</div>
</div>
```